# Using jQuery to Require Selection of Radio Button

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway to use jQuery to make the selection of a radio button required for certain values of an array? Can someone either help me or point me in the right direction? :)

**Situation:** I am building a game in which the question changes value based on an array. There are 4 radio buttons and I want the end-user to select one of these if the array is between values 1 and 5 (for example) but not for any other value.

**Edit Part 1:** 
I **only** want to use jQuery to make the selection of a radio button required because the radio buttons actually appear throughout the page regardless of array value, but I am hiding them unless the array takes a value of 1 through 5 only, so I guess this is why I *have* to use jQuery.

**Edit Part 2:**
This is what I have tried so far:
    /*I want the end user to be required to enter in a value to be able
    to move onto the next question*/

```
var reqChoice = $('answerChoice');
    reqChoice[0].required = true;
    reqChoice[1].required = true;
    reqChoice[2].required = true;
    reqChoice[3].required = true;
```

I added commented this out because it was not working, so I left it there in my program as a way of keeping notes for the future.

```
<body>
    <section class="headingIntroduction">
        <div class="headingTitle">
            <h2>Welcome to the Halloween Quiz Game!</h2>
            <hr/>
            <!--The paragraph tag directly below this
            is left blank because when the game starts, I want
            it to be blank. I only want it to have content on one 
            particular part of the program only.
            -->
            <p></p>
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="formInput">
            <form>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice0" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice0"/><span></span>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice1" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice1"/><span></span>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice2" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice2"/><span></span>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice3" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice3"/><span></span>
                <hr/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="submitButton">
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Click Here to Begin!"/>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="userScore">
            <h3>Score: 0 </h3>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/*
    When the page loads, I only want the welcome page to show. I want
    everything else to be hidden. Also want answer choices to remain hidden.
*/

$('form').hide();
$('h3').show();


var gameBegin = [
{/*Instructions Page*/
    question: 'Welcome to the Game Instructions Page!',
    instructions:'  You will be presented with several questions. Below each question are a set of answers. Select the answer that you think is correct and then click the "Submit" button to see if your answer is correct. At the end of the game, you will see your final score to let you know how you did.Choose carefully! Once you move onto the next question, you cannot go back!',
    choice: '',
    correctAnswer: '',
    buttonValue: 'Start Game!'
},
{/*question One*/
    question: 'What Film Series is Freddy Krueger From?',
    instructions: 'Question 1 out of 5',
    choice: ['A Nightmare on Elm Street', 'Simpsons Treehouse of Horror', '28 Days Later', 'The Texas Chainsaw Massacre'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Two*/
    question: 'Which Terrifying Villian Uses a Chainsaw to Murder His Victims?',
    instructions: 'Question 2 out of 5',
    choice: ['Jason Voorhees', 'Dracula', 'Frankenstein', 'Leatherface'],
    correctAnswer: 3,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Three*/
    question: 'What is the Occupation of Sweeney Todd?',
    instructions: 'Question 3 out of 5',
    choice: ['Teacher', 'Priest', 'Barber', 'Doctor'],
    correctAnswer: 2,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Four*/
    question: 'Who are the villians in the 1993 film "Hocus Pocus?"',
    instructions: 'Question 4 out of 5',
    choice: ['The Sanderson Sisters', 'Vlad the Impaler', 'Jigsaw', 'The Blair Witch'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Five*/
    question: 'Which Serial Killer is Leatherface Based On?',
    instructions: 'Question 5 out of 5',
    choice: ['Ted Bundy', 'Ed Gein', 'Charles Manson', 'Jack the Ripper'],
    correctAnswer: 1,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Game Finished Screen*/
    question: 'Congratulations! You Finished The Halloween Quiz Game!',
    instructions: 'To play again, click the button below.',
    choice: '',
    correctAnswer: '',
    buttonValue: 'Start New Game'
}
]

/*global variables*/

var gameBeginValue = 0;
var gameScore = 0;

/*Updating the current score*/
var gameScoreLabel = $('h3');




/*Moving from Page to Page When Clicking Submit Button*/

$('#submitButton').on('click',function(){



    /*I want the gameBeginValue to reset back to 0 to start a new game
    There is no need to reshow the welcome page again. I also want
    the radio buttons to only appear if the user is looking at a 
    question. I am also resetting the score back to 0 because
    a new game is started.  */

    if(gameBeginValue > 6){
        gameBeginValue = 0;
        gameScore = 0;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = 'Score: ' +  gameScore;
    } else if ((gameBeginValue < 1) || (gameBeginValue > 5)) {
        $('form').hide();
    }else{
        $('form').show();
    }


    /*Heading at top of Page*/
    var questionTitle = $('h2');
    questionTitle[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].question;

    /*The information section for playing the game*/
    var gameInformation = $('p');
    gameInformation[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].instructions;

    /*Changing the values of the input choices based on question.*/
    var questionChoice =$('span');
    questionChoice[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[0];
    questionChoice[1].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[1];
    questionChoice[2].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[2];
    questionChoice[3].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[3];

    /*Changing the value of the submit button based on what screen you are on */
    var buttonDescription = $("#submitButton");
    buttonDescription[0].value = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].buttonValue;

    /*This is what I am using to choose which question is correct based
    on what radio button the user selects. */
    if (gameBeginValue==1){
        question1();
    }else if (gameBeginValue==2){
        question2();
    }else if (gameBeginValue==3){
        question3();
    }else if (gameBeginValue==4){
        question4();
    }else if (gameBeginValue==5){
        question5();
    }

    /*I want the user to have to enter in a radio button before going to next screen*/

    /*var reqChoice0 = $('#answerChoice0');
    var reqChoice1 = $('#answerChoice1');
    var reqChoice2 = $('#answerChoice2');
    var reqChoice3 = $('#answerChoice3');*/

    if ((gameBeginValue > 0) && (gameBeginValue < 6)) {
        $('form').validate({
            rules:{
            answerChoice0:{
                required: true
            },
            answerChoice1:{
                required: true
            },
            answerChoice2:{
                required: true
            },
            answerChoice3:{
                required: true
            }
        }
    })
    }

    /*$('form').validate({
        rules:{
            if ((gameBeginValue > 0) && (gameBeginValue < 6)) {
                if ((reqChoice0.is('checked', false)) || (reqChoice1.is('checked',false)) || (reqChoice2.is('checked',false)) || (reqChoice3.is('checked',false))) {
                    alert('select an answer please');
                }
            }
        }
    })*/


    /*I want the gameBeginValue variable to increase everytime this button is clicked
    But I want it to Happen Last.*/
    $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', false);

    gameBeginValue++;

    /*I want the radio buttons to all be unchecked at the start of the
    next question*/
    $('#answerChoice0').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice1').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice2').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice3').prop('checked',false);


})

/*Updates the end users score and tells them if they are correct or not*/
/*Question 1*/
function question1(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;  
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}
/*Various functions are called based on which question
the user is on*/

/*Question 2*/
function question2(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}
/*Question 3*/
function question3(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}
/*Question 4*/
function question4(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}

/*Question 5*/

function question5(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}


})
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: please provide what you tried so far..

Comment: I added the code and provided what I have tried so far. Please let me know if you need anything else. I am new to jQuery and not exactly what you would call an expert by *anybody's* definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am incredibly appreciative of all help that I receive, I had some issues with the answer provided by "Travus Gonzalez" because I am inexperienced at writing code (I really can just do simple stuff, but I'm learning and trying to become better), so instead what I did was the following:

1. If the end-user is on a question (array value 1 through 5), the button used to move to the next question is disabled unless the end-user selects a radio button answer.
2. My problem is now solved, thank you for your help anyway guys!

I posted my new code below in case anyone wants to see it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/*
    When the page loads, I only want the welcome page to show. I want
    everything else to be hidden. Also want answer choices to remain hidden.
*/

$('form').hide();
$('h3').show();


var gameBegin = [
{/*Instructions Page*/
    question: 'Welcome to the Game Instructions Page!',
    instructions:'  You will be presented with several questions. Below each question are a set of answers. Select the answer that you think is correct and then click the "Submit" button to see if your answer is correct. At the end of the game, you will see your final score to let you know how you did.Choose carefully! Once you move onto the next question, you cannot go back!',
    choice: '',
    correctAnswer: '',
    buttonValue: 'Start Game!'
},
{/*question One*/
    question: 'What Film Series is Freddy Krueger From?',
    instructions: 'Question 1 out of 5',
    choice: ['A Nightmare on Elm Street', 'Simpsons Treehouse of Horror', '28 Days Later', 'The Texas Chainsaw Massacre'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Two*/
    question: 'Which Terrifying Villian Uses a Chainsaw to Murder His Victims?',
    instructions: 'Question 2 out of 5',
    choice: ['Jason Voorhees', 'Dracula', 'Frankenstein', 'Leatherface'],
    correctAnswer: 3,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Three*/
    question: 'What is the Occupation of Sweeney Todd?',
    instructions: 'Question 3 out of 5',
    choice: ['Teacher', 'Priest', 'Barber', 'Doctor'],
    correctAnswer: 2,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Four*/
    question: 'Who are the villians in the 1993 film "Hocus Pocus?"',
    instructions: 'Question 4 out of 5',
    choice: ['The Sanderson Sisters', 'Vlad the Impaler', 'Jigsaw', 'The Blair Witch'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Five*/
    question: 'Which Serial Killer is Leatherface Based On?',
    instructions: 'Question 5 out of 5',
    choice: ['Ted Bundy', 'Ed Gein', 'Charles Manson', 'Jack the Ripper'],
    correctAnswer: 1,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Game Finished Screen*/
    question: 'Congratulations! You Finished The Halloween Quiz Game!',
    instructions: 'To play again, click the button below.',
    choice: '',
    correctAnswer: '',
    buttonValue: 'Start New Game'
}
]

/*global variables*/

var gameBeginValue = 0;
var gameScore = 0;

/*Updating the current score*/
var gameScoreLabel = $('h3');




/*Moving from Page to Page When Clicking Submit Button*/

$('#submitButton').on('click',function(){



    /*I want the gameBeginValue to reset back to 0 to start a new game
    There is no need to reshow the welcome page again. I also want
    the radio buttons to only appear if the user is looking at a 
    question. I am also resetting the score back to 0 because
    a new game is started.  */

    if(gameBeginValue > 6){
        gameBeginValue = 0;
        gameScore = 0;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = 'Score: ' +  gameScore;
    } else if ((gameBeginValue < 1) || (gameBeginValue > 5)) {
        $('form').hide();
    }else{
        $('form').show();
    }


    /*Heading at top of Page*/
    var questionTitle = $('h2');
    questionTitle[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].question;

    /*The information section for playing the game*/
    var gameInformation = $('p');
    gameInformation[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].instructions;

    /*Changing the values of the input choices based on question.*/
    var questionChoice =$('span');
    questionChoice[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[0];
    questionChoice[1].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[1];
    questionChoice[2].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[2];
    questionChoice[3].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[3];

    /*Changing the value of the submit button based on what screen you are on */
    var buttonDescription = $("#submitButton");
    buttonDescription[0].value = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].buttonValue;

    /*This is what I am using to choose which question is correct based
    on what radio button the user selects. */
    if (gameBeginValue==1){
        question1();
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }else if (gameBeginValue==2){
        question2();
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }else if (gameBeginValue==3){
        question3();
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }else if (gameBeginValue==4){
        question4();
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }else if (gameBeginValue==5){
        question5();
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }

    /*I want the user to have to enter in a radio button before going to next screen*/


    /*I want the gameBeginValue variable to increase everytime this button is clicked
    But I want it to Happen Last.*/
    $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', false);

    gameBeginValue++;

    /*I want the radio buttons to all be unchecked at the start of the
    next question*/
    $('#answerChoice0').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice1').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice2').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice3').prop('checked',false);


})

/*Updates the end users score and tells them if they are correct or not*/
/*Question 1*/
function question1(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;  
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);

    })
}
/*Various functions are called based on which question
the user is on*/

/*Question 2*/
function question2(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);

    })
}
/*Question 3*/
function question3(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);

    })
}
/*Question 4*/
function question4(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);

    })
}

/*Question 5*/

function question5(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Correct!');
        gameScore = gameScore + 1;
        gameScoreLabel[0].textContent = "Score: " + gameScore;
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);

    })
}


})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want the jQuery validate plugin. http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/
Look threw the examples on that page, I think you will find what you are looking for specifically the example marked "Makes 'parent' required only if age is below 13".

Comment: That is in the right ballpark of what I am looking to do. I was hoping to find a solution without the plugin though (I am new to jQuery and I was hoping to just use what I have, jQuery and JavaScript, but I do appreciate the help though!)

Comment: You could roll your own validation if you wanted but it is very simple to use a jQuery plugin. Add the lines 
`<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>`

Below where you include your jQuery script and then call call the validate method like they show in the examples.

Comment: Okay, let me spend some time playing with the plugin, and I'll respond to this post if I have any questions or having any issues using it. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it! I'll let you know how this goes!

Comment: I put in my best attempt to what my code should be. I keep getting this error message: "Unexpected token ("  on the line where it says "if ((gameBeginValue > 0) && (gameBeginValue < 6)) {" Do you know why? I believe I have everything set up for this and I don't see where I have anything out of place.